# Layout responsivo em uma imagem

Tags: html, css, layout-responsivo

Bom dia caros programadores, hoje volto a pertubá-los com minha dúvidas de iniciantes. Queria saber por que não consigo fazer essa imagem responsiva com tamanho diminuido(No caso coloquei 80%), quando faço isso fica sobrando esse espaço, e no 100% fica normal.

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
@font-face {
    font-family: Agency FB;
    src: url(../_fontes/agencyfb.ttf);
}
html {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
/*Corpo do site*/
.postagem {
 background-color: rgba(255,140,40,.0px;);
 margin: 0px;
 font-family: arial; 
 font-size: 1.2vw;
}
/*Divisão de conteudo do meu site*/
#interface {
 width: 85%;
 background-color: white;
 margin: 110px auto 10px auto;
 box-shadow: 0px 4px 6px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
 }
#interface2 {
 width: 85%;
 margin: 110px auto 10px auto;
 }
/*Cabeçalho do meu site*/
.cabecalho {
 position: fixed;
 top: 0px;
 width: 100%;
 background-color: rgba(255,140,40,1);
 transition: 4s;
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
} 
.logo {
 text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
 position: relative;
 float: right;
 padding: 0px;
 margin: 25px 38% 0px 0px;
 color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
 font-family: 'Agency FB';
 font-size: 1.8vw;
}
#fcor {
 color: rgba(255,220,180,1);
}
/*Menu*/
.menu {
 float: left;
}
.mn {
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
 list-style: none;
 text-transform: uppercase;
}
.icon{
 -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.2));
    filter: drop-shadow(1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.2));
}
.mn a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: white;
}
.im {
 text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
 font-weight: 600;
 text-align: center;
 color: white;
 font-size: 0.8vw;
 transition: 0s;
 font-family: 'Agency FB';
 padding: 10px 10px 22px 10px;
 margin: 0px;
 display: inline-block;
}
.efc {
}
.im:hover {
 transition: 0.2s;
 background-color: rgba(244,116,0,1);
}
/*Postagens*/
.artigo {
 padding: 15px 25px 15px 25px;
}

.titulo {
 font-family: arial;
 font-size: 12pt;
 color: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
 margin: 0px 0px 5px 0px; 
 padding: 0px;
}

.paragrafo {
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
 color: rgba(0,0,0,.6);
 font-family: arial;
 text-align: justify;
}
.li {
 font-size: 20pt;
 font-weight: 900;
}
.link {
 color: black;
 text-decoration: none;
}
.link:hover {
 font-style: none;
 text-decoration: underline;
}
.icone {
 transition: 2s;
 border: solid white 6px;
 box-shadow: 4px 4px 6px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
 height: 400px;
 width: 600px;
}
/*Folhas de estilo de tabela*/
.tabela {
 border-collapse: collapse;
}
.tdn {
 border: solid black 2px;
 padding: 2px;
}
.vazio {
 border: solid black 2px;
 padding: 12px;
}
.vazio#vm {
 padding: 36px;
}
.tabt {
 background-color: white: ;
 padding: 2px;
 border: solid black 2px;
}
.subt {
 background-color: lightgray;
 padding: 2px;
 border: solid black 2px;
}
.ft {
 border: solid black 2px;
}
.asst {
 padding: 12px;
 font-weight: 900;
 text-align: center;
}
@charset "UTF-8";
.galeria {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 5px
}
.galeria a {
  margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  padding: 0px;
}
.post {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  background-color: black;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
  width: 80%;
  height: 80%
}
.imgp {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%
  }

.legenda {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.7);
  font-size: 1vw;
  
}
.post:hover .legenda {
  transition: 0.2s;
  background-color: rgba(244,116,0,1);
}
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="pt-br">
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="icon" href="_imagens/icon.png" type="image/x-icon" />
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="_imagens/icon.png" type="image/x-icon" />
  <title>Processos e Manuais de Instruções</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="_css/estilo.css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="_css/fotos.css"/>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script>
 $(document).scroll(function() {
 var y = $(this).scrollTop();
 if (y < 25) {
  $('.logo').css({'margin': '25px 38% 0px 0px'});
  $('.im').css({'padding': '10px 10px 22px 10px'});
  $('.icon').css({'display': 'inline-block'});
  $('.efc').css({'display': 'initial'});
  $('.cabecalho').css({'transition': '4s'});
 } else {
  $('.logo').css({'margin': '3px 38% 0px 0px'});
  $('.im').css({'padding': '10px 10px 10px 10px'});
  $('.icon').css({'display': 'none'});
  $('.efc').css({'display': 'none'});
  $('.cabecalho').css({'transition': '4s'});
 }
 });
 </script>
 </head>
 <body class="postagem">
   <header class="cabecalho">
    <nav class="menu">
     <h1 hidden="true">Menu Principal</h1>
     <ul class="mn"> 
            <a href="index.html"><li class="im"><img class="icon" src="https://image.ibb.co/hEiU5f/icasa.png"><br class="efc">Home</li></a><!--  
         --><a href="index.html"><li class="im"><img class="icon" src="https://image.ibb.co/f46hQf/ilivro.png"><br class="efc">Manuais e Processos</li></a><!--  
         --><a href="index.html"><li class="im"><img class="icon" src="https://image.ibb.co/it5bkf/iferramentas.png"><br class="efc">Equipamentos</li></a><!--  
         --><a href="index.html"><li class="im"><img class="icon" src="https://image.ibb.co/irX0BL/ietiqueta.png"><br class="efc">Inventário</li></a>
     </ul>
    </nav>
    <h1 class="logo">MANUAIS E PROCESSOS<span id="fcor"> INFORMÁTICA</span></h1> 
   </header>
  <div id="interface">
   <section class="galeria">
    <a href="_postagem/1009182.html">
     <figure class="post">
      <img class="imgp" src="https://image.ibb.co/kORwJ0/check.jpg">
      <figcaption class="legenda">Checklist de manutenção de computador</figcaption>
     </figure>
    </a>
    <a href="_postagem/1009181.html">
     <figure class="post">
      <img class="imgp" src="https://image.ibb.co/gbsE5f/win10.jpg">
      <figcaption class="legenda">Instalar sistema operacional (Windows 10)</figcaption>
      </figure>
    </a>
    <a href="_postagem/1009185.html">
     <figure class="post">
      <img class="imgp" src="https://image.ibb.co/iD2srL/oracle.png">
      <figcaption class="legenda">Instalar o software Oracle</figcaption>
     </figure>
    </a>
    <a href="_postagem/1009186.html">
     <figure class="post">
      <img class="imgp" src="https://image.ibb.co/iniAd0/office.png">
      <figcaption class="legenda">Instalar o pacote office</figcaption>
     </figure>
    </a>
    <a href="_postagem/1009187.html">
     <figure class="post">
      <img class="imgp" src="https://image.ibb.co/dMaZ5f/vnc.png">
      <figcaption class="legenda">Instalar UltraVNC Viewer</figcaption>
     </figure>
    </a>
    
   </section>
  </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Então, esse é o problema, eu consigo diminuir o tamanho da imagem e legenda, mas fica sobrendo esse espaço que é do link, queria diminuir também mas não consigo. E também outra dúvida sobre layout responsivo é nos ícones do menu, não consigo colocar

```
img { 
max-width: 100%
height: auto;
}
```

pra ele se ajustar a página...
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Cara não entendi direito seu problema, onde fica sobrando espaço? Qual imagem vc está falando a logo? Se possível coloca um print ai do seu problema

Comment: Ao colocar imagem com 80%, ela e a legenda diminuiu como pode ver na página, mas o link tem um tamanho definido que não consigo alterar

Answer (score 1):

Cara seu problema é que vc está usando as propriedade nos lugares errados. Por exemplo vc esta usando `padding` no link quando na verdade deveria usar `margin` na classe .`post`

Outra coisa, se vc quer que fique com 100% de largura vc não pode definir com 80%. tente aumentar a margem para "diminuir" o `.post`, pois um vai empurrar o outro do lado e eles ficarão "encolhidos".

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue o código com a correção para ficar como na imagem acima, deixei os comentários no CSS onde eu mexi, foi pouca coisa até ;)

```css
    @charset "UTF-8";
@font-face {
    font-family: Agency FB;
    src: url(../_fontes/agencyfb.ttf);
}
html {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
/*Corpo do site*/
.postagem {
 background-color: rgba(255,140,40,.0px;);
 margin: 0px;
 font-family: arial; 
 font-size: 1.2vw;
}
/*Divisão de conteudo do meu site*/
#interface {
 width: 85%;
 background-color: white;
 margin: 110px auto 10px auto;
 box-shadow: 0px 4px 6px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
 }
#interface2 {
 width: 85%;
 margin: 110px auto 10px auto;
 }
/*Cabeçalho do meu site*/
.cabecalho {
 position: fixed;
 top: 0px;
 width: 100%;
 background-color: rgba(255,140,40,1);
 transition: 4s;
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
} 
.logo {
 text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
 position: relative;
 float: right;
 padding: 0px;
 margin: 25px 38% 0px 0px;
 color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
 font-family: 'Agency FB';
 font-size: 1.8vw;
}
#fcor {
 color: rgba(255,220,180,1);
}
/*Menu*/
.menu {
 float: left;
}
.mn {
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
 list-style: none;
 text-transform: uppercase;
}
.icon{
 -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.2));
    filter: drop-shadow(1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.2));
}
.mn a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: white;
}
.im {
 text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
 font-weight: 600;
 text-align: center;
 color: white;
 font-size: 0.8vw;
 transition: 0s;
 font-family: 'Agency FB';
 padding: 10px 10px 22px 10px;
 margin: 0px;
 display: inline-block;
}
.efc {
}
.im:hover {
 transition: 0.2s;
 background-color: rgba(244,116,0,1);
}
/*Postagens*/
.artigo {
 padding: 15px 25px 15px 25px;
}

.titulo {
 font-family: arial;
 font-size: 12pt;
 color: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
 margin: 0px 0px 5px 0px; 
 padding: 0px;
}

.paragrafo {
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
 color: rgba(0,0,0,.6);
 font-family: arial;
 text-align: justify;
}
.li {
 font-size: 20pt;
 font-weight: 900;
}
.link {
 color: black;
 text-decoration: none;
}
.link:hover {
 font-style: none;
 text-decoration: underline;
}
.icone {
 transition: 2s;
 border: solid white 6px;
 box-shadow: 4px 4px 6px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
 height: 400px;
 width: 600px;
}
/*Folhas de estilo de tabela*/
.tabela {
 border-collapse: collapse;
}
.tdn {
 border: solid black 2px;
 padding: 2px;
}
.vazio {
 border: solid black 2px;
 padding: 12px;
}
.vazio#vm {
 padding: 36px;
}
.tabt {
 background-color: white: ;
 padding: 2px;
 border: solid black 2px;
}
.subt {
 background-color: lightgray;
 padding: 2px;
 border: solid black 2px;
}
.ft {
 border: solid black 2px;
}
.asst {
 padding: 12px;
 font-weight: 900;
 text-align: center;
}
@charset "UTF-8";
.galeria {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 5px
}
.galeria a {
 /* não usar esse padding */
  /* margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px; */
  padding: 0px;
}
.post {
  position: relative;
  /* coloque margem e não o padding  */
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 0px;
  background-color: black;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
  /* se vc quer que fique 100% tem que remover esses 80% */
  /* width: 80%; */
  /* height: 80% */
}
.imgp {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%
  }

.legenda {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.7);
  font-size: 1vw;
  
}
.post:hover .legenda {
  transition: 0.2s;
  background-color: rgba(244,116,0,1);
}
```

```html
   <header class="cabecalho">
    <nav class="menu">
     <h1 hidden="true">Menu Principal</h1>
     <ul class="mn"> 
            <a href="index.html"><li class="im"><img class="icon" src="https://image.ibb.co/hEiU5f/icasa.png"><br class="efc">Home</li></a><!--  
         --><a href="index.html"><li class="im"><img class="icon" src="https://image.ibb.co/f46hQf/ilivro.png"><br class="efc">Manuais e Processos</li></a><!--  
         --><a href="index.html"><li class="im"><img class="icon" src="https://image.ibb.co/it5bkf/iferramentas.png"><br class="efc">Equipamentos</li></a><!--  
         --><a href="index.html"><li class="im"><img class="icon" src="https://image.ibb.co/irX0BL/ietiqueta.png"><br class="efc">Inventário</li></a>
     </ul>
    </nav>
    <h1 class="logo">MANUAIS E PROCESSOS<span id="fcor"> INFORMÁTICA</span></h1> 
   </header>
  <div id="interface">
   <section class="galeria">
    <a href="_postagem/1009182.html">
     <figure class="post">
      <img class="imgp" src="https://image.ibb.co/kORwJ0/check.jpg">
      <figcaption class="legenda">Checklist de manutenção de computador</figcaption>
     </figure>
    </a>
    <a href="_postagem/1009181.html">
     <figure class="post">
      <img class="imgp" src="https://image.ibb.co/gbsE5f/win10.jpg">
      <figcaption class="legenda">Instalar sistema operacional (Windows 10)</figcaption>
      </figure>
    </a>
    <a href="_postagem/1009185.html">
     <figure class="post">
      <img class="imgp" src="https://image.ibb.co/iD2srL/oracle.png">
      <figcaption class="legenda">Instalar o software Oracle</figcaption>
     </figure>
    </a>
    <a href="_postagem/1009186.html">
     <figure class="post">
      <img class="imgp" src="https://image.ibb.co/iniAd0/office.png">
      <figcaption class="legenda">Instalar o pacote office</figcaption>
     </figure>
    </a>
    <a href="_postagem/1009187.html">
     <figure class="post">
      <img class="imgp" src="https://image.ibb.co/dMaZ5f/vnc.png">
      <figcaption class="legenda">Instalar UltraVNC Viewer</figcaption>
     </figure>
    </a>
    
   </section>
  </div>
```